# Background image appears inverted when viewing the webpage on iphone

Tags: jquery, iphone, html, css, safari

I am viewing my website (www.lotogleam.com) on iPhone safari browser, and surprisingly the first page ("client speaks"), opens up with the background image being upside down/inverted. The issue gets solved in the landscape mode though. Any clue why this wierd behavior?

**CSS:**

```
 .testimonial-holder { 
 background-image: url(../images/testimonial.jpg); 
 } 

 .web-article { 
background-position: center; 
background-size: cover; 
background-attachment: fixed; 
background-color: #000; 
color: #fff; 
}
```

Comment: Please show code.

Comment: It's just the css there:
.testimonial-holder {
    background-image: url(../images/testimonial.jpg);
}
.web-article {
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
}

Comment: @Wolv3rine updated your question, don't place css in comment section.